# MongoDB full text search

Tags: c#, mongodb

Create index

```
db.MyCollection.createIndex({'$**': 'text'}, {name: 'FullTextIndex'})
```

Search for match

```
db.MyCollection.find({$text: {$search: 'myWord'}}).count()
```

Result is 1. for a filed which has value "**myWord is here**"

If I do regular search for selected fields as following, I get two records, one record has Name = "**myWord is here**" and second record has "**myWord**" in Details filed as "**something here and myWord is here**"

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({  
     "$or":[{"Name":/myWord/i}, {"Details":/myWord/i}]
    }).sort({"Name": 1})
```

How can I recreate the index so that it search in all fields as SQL where any field like %searchText%

And Finally how can I write this search query in C# Driver

**Update:**

---

I further looked in to it. it is finding all results that has a search key with prefix and suffix spaces, but not part of the string in a word.

Example it is returning a record for a value "**Hello myWord is here**", but doesn't  return "**HellomyWord**"

But according to this document, it has to support wildcard search. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: MongoDB full text search doesn't support wildcards. If you want to use wildcards, use regex.

Comment: Regex on each column of the collection? All documents in my collection are not having same schema. Each document had 30 to 90 fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I haven't found, much help with wildcard search/Full text search using Mongo, I have come up with a work around for my requirement.

```
foreach (var doc in batch)
  {
     if (custDictionary.ContainsKey(projectId))
        {
           string concatenatedCustomFields = custFieldsList.Aggregate(string.Empty,
                            (current, custField) =>
                                current +
                                (ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(custField)
                                    ? (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][custField].GetType().Name == typeof(DBNull).Name
                                        ? string.Empty
                                        : ((string) ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][custField]).StripHtml())
                                    : string.Empty));

                        doc.Add("CustomFieldsConcatenated", concatenatedCustomFields);
        }
    i++;
 }
```

I read list of custom fields for each group of documents, then create a concatenated Mongo Field, then use Regex query on that field.

Then to improve the performance of the query added following index

```
  _mongoConnect.Database?.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollectionName")
                .Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new BsonDocument("CustomFieldsConcatenated", "hashed"), new CreateIndexOptions { Name = "CollectionName_FieldName_Index" });
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that wildcard characters can be included in Regex Searches but not in the full text search.

There is already a feature request ticket for this [SERVER-10227](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10227). If this is an important feature for you,please upvote the ticket.

Further adding to your comment:

> I further looked in to it. it is finding all results that has a search key with prefix and suffix spaces, but not part of the string in a word.
>
> Example it is returning a record for a value *"Hello myWord is here"*, but doesn't return *"HellomyWord"*

The $text operator matches on the complete stemmed word.There is no facility at present to deal with index positions in strings that return a meaningful value for a projection. In your use case, a search on the term *"myWord"* will not match *"HellomyWord"*. However, it matches a document containing ,e.g, *"hi myWord is here"* or *"myWord comes"* etc.

For more information, please see the [Match Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/text/#match-operation) page.

Comment: thank you for sharing this information. Though this is not a solution for my requirement, It at least give's me a clarity on what is supported in MongoDB today and when can I expect this feature.